# Unlock user without giving a password for key usage

Tags: raspbian, useradd, passwd

I'd like to setup a new user in raspbian Jessie that does not have a password and is only accessible with the correct SSH key to have a very secure of using SSH to connect to the Pi. The commands passwd and usermod won't let me unlock the user because they'll be without a password.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As **root** (you may need to run `sudo -i` or `sudo su -`) create a new user,

```
root@pi# useradd -m myuser
```

then `su` to the user

```
root@pi# su - myuser
```

and edit the file (as myuser) `~/.ssh/authorized_keys` and add the public key of another computer to it,

```
myuser@pi$ echo "your-public-key-in-here" >> ~/.ssh/authorized_keys
# or just open in vi/nano and paste the key inside it
```

Also make sure that the file permissions are Read/Write only for the owner -- myuser in this case

```
root@pi# chmod 600 /home/myuser/.ssh/authorized_keys
root@pi# chown myuser:myuser /home/myuser/.ssh/authorized_keys
```

Comment: when trying `sudo nano ~/.ssh/authorized_keys` from `myuser@raspberrypi` system is asking me for myuser's password which doesn't exist. should i simply place the key with root user into myuser's auth_keys?

Comment: no, just edit the file as `myuser` you don't need `sudo` for that.

Comment: i used sudo now as it didn't permit me to execute that without the correct password, but everything is working, i can ssh into myuser using the private key. is `chmod 600 authorized_keys` to be executed by myuser or su? it was created by su

Comment: Hi @RapidFireArts , just added some context to the commands